# Parallel coroutines execution with timeout and combine results at the end

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to implement kind of trivial use case with coroutines: sending parallel requests and then wait until all come back and merge the results in one list. I use the logic as below but somehow it does not wait for all responses but finishes (goes to flatten()) after first one is done. What am I doing wrong?

```
fun run() {
    GlobalScope.launch  {
        running = true
        results =
        providers
                .map { provider -> async { provider.retrieve() } }
                .map { retrieval ->
                    try {
                        withTimeout(2000L) {
                            retrieval.await()
                        }
                    } catch (ex: CancellationException) {
                        arrayListOf<Pair<String, String>>()
                    }
                }
                .flatten()
        running = false
        notifyObservers()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can not see anything wrong in your code.
Anyway lets see what I can do, maybe it helps.

*I assume your Provider `retrieve()` returns a list of some type `T`.*

Let's create a similar Provider class with a suspending function returning a list of `Int`:

```kotlin
class Provider(val name: String) {
  suspend fun execute(): List<Int>
}
```

Lets then create a list of 3 Providers:

```kotlin
val providers: List<Provider> = listOf(Provider("p1"), Provider("p2"), Provider("p3"))
```

Using the `map()` function on list we wrap them in a `Deferred` using `async()` function:

```kotlin
val deferredList: List<Deferred<Int>> = providers.map { provider ->
  async { provider.execute() }
}
```

**Execute Deferred**

Now we have two options, either we do another `map` operation and call `await()` on each `Deferred`:

```kotlin
val result: List<List<Int>> = deferredList.map { it.await } }
```

or we use the extension function [awaitAll()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlin.collections.-collection/await-all.html) and get the actual result as a list of Integers:

```kotlin
val result: List<List<Int>> = deferredList.awaitAll()
```

Then we can flatten the result using `flatten()`

**Put all together**

Lets create one function that gets a list of providers and returns a list of `Int`, once all suspending calls are done.

```kotlin
suspend fun executeAllProvidersConcurrently(providers: List<Provider>): List<Int> = withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
    return@withContext providers.map {
        async { it.execute() }
    }.awaitAll().flatten()
}

launch {
  println(executeAllProvidersConcurrently(providers))
}
```

As you can see I didn't do that much differently. I have created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/christianb/aabc665e59cd59990a515ef6a6d45190/) where you can get the full sample code and run it yourself.

Hope this will help you running Coroutines concurrently and fetch the result of all.